# whether CABasicAnimation runs in the any thread by default

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, swift5, cabasicanimation

I am creating a custom activity indicator, a custom view. The only public API, the user will have is the `init(onFrame frame: CGRect)`, `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()`.

So, I want to know in the `startAnimating` method, should I create a thread whether DispatchQueue.mainor DispatchQoS to run the animation.

Also, if I don't put the animation code in a thread, will it be automatically running on main thread?

Comment: It appears that there are multiple copies of this question posted by you... Is this intentional?

Comment: @Alladinian: no, there are some issues with posting questions on hat cause timeouts for some users, who then try to resubmit.

Comment: actually I was getting error while posting the question and I have no idea that it had been posted on my multiple tries.